# How do I calculate the total XP to reach a particular level, when each level takes 10% more?

Tags: mathematics, javascript

How do I calculate the amount of XP for a level where the first level is 110, and each level after is 10% more than the last. Preferably to do without a loop because the levels will have to be infinite and will need to be quickly calculated.

in js using a loop:

```
var xptest=110;
var lastLevel = 110;
for (var level = 2; xptest <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER || level < 100; level++) {

    lastLevel*=1.1;
    lastLevel = Math.round(lastLevel *1.1)
    xptest+= lastLevel;

    console.log('LEVEL',level,'('+lastLevel+' / '+xptest+')');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's work through some cases, given \$baseXP = 110\$ and \$increase = 1.1\$:

$$\begin{align}
targetXP(1) &= baseXP\\
targetXP(2) &= baseXP + baseXP \cdot increase\\
targetXP(3) &= baseXP + baseXP \cdot increase + baseXP\cdot increase^2\\
...\\
targetXP(n) &= baseXP + baseXP \cdot increase + ... + baseXP \cdot increase ^ {n-1}\\
\end{align}$$

If we multiply \$targetXP(n)\$ by \$increase\$, we find that all it does is shift the terms down one:

$$\begin{align}targetXP(n)&\cdot increase\\ &= baseXP \cdot increase + baseXP \cdot increase^2 + ...+ baseXP \cdot increase^n\end{align}$$

So if we subtract the original from this shifted version, all the terms except the first and last will cancel out, and we get...

$$\begin{align}
targetXP(n) \cdot increase - targetXP(n) &= baseXP \cdot increase^n - baseXP\\
  targetXP(n) \cdot (increase - 1) &= baseXP \cdot (increase^n - 1)\\
targetXP(n) &= baseXP \cdot \frac {1 - increase^n} {1 - increase}\end{align}$$

[This is what's called a Geometric Series - you can read more about the math behind this here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)

Comment: Thanks, I don't entirely understand it, but it definitely works Math.round(110*((1-Math.pow(1.1,level))/(1-1.1)),0);

Answer (score 2):

You're correct to want to use a technique which is more professional and elegant than a brute force loop!  [;)

$$XP_{next} = XP_{initial} (1 + Rate_{level})^{Level_{current}}$$

This is the compound interest formula.  "Rate_level" is rate per level.

So, you're level five and you want to know the XP for level six:

$$\begin{align}
NextLevel = 110(1+0.10)^5\\
= 110(1.10)^5\\
= 110 \times 1.61051\\
= 177.1561\\
\end{align}$$

Rounded down is 177xp.

To find what level you're currently at based on your current experience points:

$$Level_{current} = log_{(1+Rate_{initial})}\left(\frac{XP_{current}}{XP_{initial}}\right)$$

10% is quite a steep progression curve, but it sounds like you know what you're doing and that you want it that way.  If this were a D&D style RPG I would lean more toward 195% to 210% per level progression, which would imply a relatively limited number of levels.

Good luck.