# Bulk level when user gets bulk exp

Tags: algorithm

I've been working with this for the entire week now, this is about a leveling system of my application. When a user gets the enough exp needed, it gets leveled up, everything works fine. But, when a user gets a bulk exp, it won't get a bulk level as well. The default for exp needed for every user is 1000. For example:

The user gets 1000 exp, for level 1, it gets leveled up to level 2. It works fine that way, but if it gets more than the exp needed the flow won't work the same way. Because the exp needed for level 2, is 1400. So the algorithm for this if the user gets enough or more than the exp needed, the current exp_needed for the next level is multiplied by 1.4.

```
if($user->level <= 19){
   while($user->curr_exp >= $user->exp_needed){
   $user->level += 1;
   $user->curr_exp -= $user->exp_needed;   
   $user->prev_exp = $user->exp_needed;
   $user->exp_needed = $user->prev_exp * 1.4;
   $user->save();
  }
}
elseif($user->level >= 20){
 while($user->curr_exp >= $user->exp_needed){
 $user->level += 1;
 $user->curr_exp -= $user->exp_needed;   
 $user->prev_exp = $user->exp_needed;
 $user->exp_needed = $user->prev_exp * 1.1;
 $user->save();
 }
}
```

Edit : The levels 1-20 and their exp_needed is working fine now, but when I'm at Level 21, I'm having troubles with the exp, because the exp_needed at level 21 should only be multiplied by 1.1,

For example,

Scenario 1:
The User will earn a curr_exp(current exp) of 2,100,000 the user will jump on to level 21 with an experience of 836,6825.55 which is wrong because the exp_needed at level 21 should be the sum of the prev_exp(level 20 = 597,630.40) multiplied by 1.1 which will be

(prev_exp of level 20) 597,630.40 * 1.1 =  657,393.44

Scenario 2:

The user gets an exp of 2,000,000 it will be on the level 20 with an exp of 508,424.01 with an exp_needed of 597,630.40 and when it gets another exp of 100,000 the user will be leveled up to 21 with an exp_needed of 657,393.44 which is correct.

So to summarize each scenarios results:

Scenario 1:

```
Level 21
Exp:10,793.61
Previous Exp: 597,630.44
Exp Needed for the next level: 836,682.55
```

Scenario 2:

```
Level 21
Exp: 10,793.61
Previous Exp: 597,630.40
Exp needed for the next level: 657,393.44
```

Scenario 2 should be the results I am seeking for but it doesn't work that way on my while loop. Any ideas how to deal with this? Thank you.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/163657/how-do-i-calculate-the-total-xp-to-reach-a-particular-level-when-each-level-tak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually as simple as

```
while (expReceived > expNeededForNextLevel) {
    expReceived -= expNeededForNextLevel
    levelup()
}
```

Comment: sir, what if I'll change the equations, from levels 1-20 the exp_needed will be multiplied by 1.4, and 21 to 40 will be multiplied by 1.1?

Comment: I'm actually having troubles when the user gets more than enough exp at level 20, that the user will eventually level to 21, at level 20, its exp is 597,630. so the exp at level 21 should be 657,393.44

Comment: @John You could even use a lookup table for exp values per level. Levelup() would in this case manipulate the expNeededForNextLevel variable, which is then reassessed in the same while loop.

Comment: @Peethor sir, I don't actually get that part, could you please show me an example on how to do that?

Comment: I just saw you edited the question. Nevermind my comment. Make one big while loop, and do the if statement inside that

Comment: I already did but I guess something's missing on my equation, everything is fine from 1-19, 21-39. but 20-21 and 39-41 isn't right for some reason

Comment: @JohnCarlo because if the level is 19, it goes into the first part, updates the level to 20 and sets the next required exp to curretn required * 1.4. Lower the 19 and 20 by one

Comment: @Bálint Sir, I've already lowered 19 and 20 by one, but I stil get the same results.

Comment: @Bálint I even moved the level + 1 before the user->save. But, it still gets the same results.

Comment: Okay, now I get it. I should've put the if else statement inside the while loop. now it gets the results I am seeking for, thank you so much!